# Set theory in the "An Introduction to Mathematical Thinking "

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let

$$P=\{x\in\mathbb R \mid \sin(x) = 0\}\qquad\text{and}\qquad Q=\{ n\pi \mid n\in\mathbb Z \}.$$

What is the relationship between $P$ and $Q$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Hint: solve the equation $\sin(x)=0$ and draw conclusions.

Comment: Consider that $Q=\{x\in \Bbb R| x/\pi\in \Bbb Z\}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left\{\begin{array}{c} q \in Q \Longrightarrow \exists_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}: q=n\pi \Longrightarrow \sin(q) = \sin(n\pi) = 0 \Longrightarrow q \in P \Longrightarrow Q \subseteq P \\
p \in P \Longrightarrow \sin(p) = 0 \Longrightarrow \exists_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}: p=n\pi \Longrightarrow p \in Q \Longrightarrow P \subseteq Q \\ \end{array}\right\} \Longrightarrow P=Q$$